# LINQ Bug ? Get a string array from a list of long

Tags: linq-to-objects

I'm getting this 
     `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.`
from following code snippet:

```
 IList<long> Ids = new List<long>();
 Ids.Add(6962056);
 Ids.Add(7117210);
 Ids.Add(13489241);

 var stringIds = Ids.Cast<string>().ToArray();
```

and Booooooooooooom .... ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot *cast* a long to a string.  You need to specify what operation to perform to turn the longs into strings.  I prefer using Linq to select out the new values:

```
var stringIds = Ids.Select(id => id.ToString());
```

Comment: So you have to select/convert the source values ... I thought Cast() was much cleverer in once a string is the target type, it should simple call .ToString() by itself on the source type.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you can not cast longs to strings.

You're confusing

```
long l = 10;
string s = (string)l; // this will not work, l is not a string
```

with

```
long l = 10;
string s = l.ToString(); // this will work
```

Comment: This clears out what .Cast<XXX>() is doing. I thought it was calling .ToString()... so thanks for the explanation.